# Create and apply migrations for all databases in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have `ApplicationDbContext`, which dynamically change connection string to database, which depends on user's library name. So, for each library, I have it's own database. When I'm creating migrations and apply them, they are related only to default database with default connection string, where no library name defined.

How can I make and apply migrations to all this databases, that dynamically created, that depends on library name (they exist after creation, they are fully defined and working databases)?

Comment: You could use code based migrations where you iterate through each connection string: https://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/

Comment: @SteveGreene this is not working with EF Core.

Comment: Yeah, EF core is pretty raw. You might find a hint here in the Startup.cs file https://github.com/rowanmiller/UnicornStore/tree/master/UnicornStore/src/UnicornStore

Comment: @SteveGreene really, I can't find it. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: There is code in his startup.cs to execute migrations. I don't see a lot of documentation on it, but maybe it will give you a hint. See the lines near serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();

Comment: EF 6 seems to have what you need. EF Core is still unreleased and you may have issues when trying more complicated use cases.

Comment: @SteveGreene seems that this line `serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.Migrate‌​();` refers to Development environment, so, we should just write it in Debug version and that's just all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you properly, you should implement the following:

1) Implement Service that will migrate your schema and seed data. (despite what they did in the [latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#data-seeding), I still prefer my implementation)

Helper

```
    public static async Task EnsureSeedData(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        using (var scope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            // here could be several seed services if necessary
            var seedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISeedService>();
            await seedService.MigrateAsync();
            await seedService.SeedAsync();
        }
    }
```

ISeedService Interface

```
internal interface ISeedService
{
    Task MigrateAsync();
    Task SeedAsync();
}
```

SeedService Implementation

```
internal sealed class SeedService : ISeedService
{
    private readonly InitializeContext _identityContext;

    public SeedService(InitializeContext identityContext)
    {
        _identityContext = identityContext;
    }

    public async Task MigrateAsync()
    {
        await _identityContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
    }

    public async Task SeedAsync()
    {
        if (_identityContext.AllMigrationsApplied())
        {
            var strategy = _identityContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
            await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
            {
                using (var transaction = await _identityContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
                {
                    // seed data if necessary
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs file

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await SeedData.EnsureSeedData(host.Services);
        }).Wait();
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

2) Register context and related services in DI, which will allow dynamically retrieve connection string. There are several ways to do it, my implementation is not the best one, so it's up to you.

Startup.cs file

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<ISeedService, SeedService>();
        services.AddScoped<IDbConfiguration, FakeDbConfiguration>();
        services.AddDbContext<InitializeContext>((provider, builder) =>
        {
            var dbConfiguration = provider.GetService<IDbConfiguration>();
            builder.UseSqlServer(dbConfiguration.Connection);
        });

        // omitted
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // omitted
    }
}
```

DbConfiguration file.

```
internal sealed class FakeDbConfiguration : IDbConfiguration
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public FakeDbConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    // REPLACE THIS PART WITH YOURS IMPLEMENTATION
    public string Connection => _configuration["Database:Connection"];
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: @YuriyN. if it works for you and solve you real problem, accept answer please. Otherwise, let me know and I will improve/extend it.

Comment: honestly, currently I'm working on absolutely another problem and can't check that, but I will accept this answer, let the other user say more about it.